# How to execute something in ionic when app is being run for the first time?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to run a bunch of commands when my app is executed for the first time. I found a few pieces of code but none of them seem to work for me. Here is what i have right now :

```
  var applaunchCount = this.storage.get('launchCount');
  console.log(applaunchCount);

    if(applaunchCount){
          this.hello="succesive";
     }else{
    storage.set('launchCount','1');
        this.hello="first";
    }
```

I tried it on my android device the value of hello always remains "succesive".
Edit : 
The home.ts file which is the first page

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {cloths} from '../defaults.component';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})


export class HomePage {
hello : string;
clothes=cloths;
l : string ;
public loginForm = this.fb.group({
    new: ["", ]

  });


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public fb:FormBuilder, public storage:Storage) {
  var applaunchCount = this.storage.get('launchCount');
  var app : string;
  console.log(applaunchCount);

    if(applaunchCount){
    //This is a second time launch, and count = applaunchCount
          this.hello="succesive";
     }else{
    //Local storage is not set, hence first time launch. set the local storage item
    storage.set('launchCount','1');
        this.hello="first";
     //Do the other stuff related to first time launch
    }

  }
  buttonLogin(){

    this.clothes.push(this.loginForm.get('new').value);


  }


}
```

Comment: what is the value of `applaunchCount`

Comment: add your code inside the constructor of app.component.ts

Comment: @Duannx The log statement shows nothing. Its empty

Comment: Change `var applaunchCount = this.storage.get('launchCount');` to `var applaunchCount = storage.get('launchCount');` and  `if(applaunchCount)` to  `if(applaunchCount==true)`

Answer (score 0):

Getting data from the Storage is an `async` operation, so you have to wait until the data is ready before using it:

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public fb:FormBuilder, public storage:Storage) {

    let app : string; // <- You can use let instead of var here

    this.storage.get('launchCount').then(applaunchCount => { // <- Wait for the data to be ready

        // Now the data from the storage is ready!

        console.log(applaunchCount);

        if(applaunchCount) {
            // This is a second time launch, and count = applaunchCount
            this.hello = "succesive";
        } else {
            // Local storage is not set, hence first time launch. set the local storage item
            storage.set('launchCount','1');

            this.hello = "first";

            // Do the other stuff related to first time launch
        }
    });

}
```